# #temp_table vs user.#temp_table sybase_iq

Tags: sql, database, temp-tables, sap-iq

i wonder what is the difference between #temp_table and user.#temp_table

```
 -- 1) #Tem_table

  create table #temp_table
   ( id integer null);

 select * from #temp_table  -- find

select * from sysobjects where name = '#temp_table'-- not found
```

-- close my client

```
 select * from #temp_table -- not found

--2) user.#temp_table
 create table user.#temp_table
   ( id integer null);

  select * from user.#temp_table  -- found


 select * from sysobjects where name = '#temp_table'  --  found
```

-- close my client

```
  select * from sysobjects where name = '#temp_table'  -- still exist
```

My Main question is, why

```
 select * from sysobjects where name = '#temp_table'
```

return nothing, and with user.

```
  select * from sysobjects where name = '#temp_table'
```

returns the info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you add user_name.#Table_name Sybase ignore automatically the #. What are you creating  is a normal user Table. In fact if you check it with

```
 select * from sysobjects where name = '#temp_table'
```

the type should be 'U' what means that you have created a user table = not temporary table at all.

Best Regards, Enrique